# Error with std::bind and templated member functions

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, pointers

I am currently writing a gameboy emulator for practicing C++. I have gotten to the part where I implement CPU instructions and decided a vector of std::function was a good choice.

Please note: `u8` is an alias for `uint8_t`.

In my code, there is a vector of `std::function<u8()>` with three types of members:

1. A lambda expression that returns `u8`.
2. Pointer to a member function.
3. Pointer to a templated member function.

I tried to use an initalizer list at first, but it didn't work. I later found out that is because I needed a call to `std::bind(/*function ptr*/, this);` on the pointers, but when calling this on the templated function pointers, I get the following error: `no matching function for call to 'bind'`. I would like to have an initalizer list, as right now it is a function with successive calls to `emplace_back`.

Here is the erroring line:

`instruction_set.emplace_back(bind(&CPU::OPLoadDualRegister8<B, B>, this)); // 0x40 LD B, B`

One interesting thing is that when `B` is replaced with a literal (e.g. `0x00`) it works perfectly. `B` is a `u8` and that is what the template accepts.

So:

1. Is there any way I can do this less convoluted? (e.g. init lists, std::function with member function ptrs, etc.)
2. If this is the best way, what do I do about the templated ptrs?
3. Would it better if I took the template params as args and used `std::bind` to resolve them (all params are either `u8` or `u8&`.
4. Any optimization suggestions?

Thanks, Zach.

Comment: Have you instantiated your `CPU::OPLoadDualRegister8<B, B>` before passing it to `std::bind()`?

Comment: If that's it I'm going to be so mad... (Not at you of course). No, they haven't. Is `template u8 CPU::OPLoadDualRegister8<B, B>();` at the top of my cpp file sufficient?

Comment: You'd have to instantiate it with literals (like the `0x00` that you had above). If you want to keep `B` as a parameter to call a different function at runtime depending on `B`, you'd have to use dispatch (say a `switch` statement) or a lookup table (perhaps `std::unordered_map<u8, std::function<u8()>>`). I fell into the same trap once. :)

Comment: Is there any way to have it use the variable B? As in every time I call it, use the value of B in the class in the load. Also the first B parameter is `u8&`.

Comment: Yes, that's what `std::unordered_map` is good for. I imagine that you will have a fixed number of functions to call. If you create a map like `std::unordered_map<u8, std::function<u8()>> funcs`, you can pre-fill it with functions and then call the appropriate one like this: `B b1; B b2 = funcs.at(b1)()`. `std::unordered_map` has a lookup time of `O(1)`, so that should be suitable for an emulator.

Comment: P.S. this will also work if your `b1` is a reference (`B&`).

Comment: B is a class member and can take on all values 0-0xFF. I have this for at least 70 instructions so that's 256*70 entries. Is there a better way?

Comment: The map will handle that many entries, however, if you think that this would be tedious to generate, simply pass `B` as an argument to the function (you already thought of that). Bear in mind that `std::bind` copies all arguments passed to it unless they are explicitly wrapped in `std::ref` (I fell into _that_ trap as well...).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there is a lot going on here between your question and the comments. Here are some things I notice right off the bat:

1. If you are going to index into a vector to decode op codes, you probably shouldn't just emplace_back into the vector in order. Instead grow the vector to its final size, filling it with null values and use the subscript operator to put the functions in. `instruction_set[0x40] = ...`
2. Using a `switch` statement and just calling the functions directly is likely a way better choice. Obviously, don't know the ins and outs of your project, so this may not be possible.
3. When you say `B` is `u8` do you mean `B` is variable of type `u8`? Plain 'ol variables can't be used to instantiate templates. `B` would have to be a macro, template parameter on the calling function, `constexpr` variable, or `static const` (basically known at compile time).
4. `std::bind` is never any fun for anyone to use, so you are not alone. I don't think it is the root cause of your issue here, but you should probably prefer binding things using capturing lambdas.

Funnily enough C++'s new hearthrob Matt Godbolt (author of [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/)) gave a [talk on emulating a 6502 in JavaScript](https://youtu.be/7WuRq-Wmw5o?t=15m50s) last year. It's not exactly an authoritative reference on the subject, but it may be worth a watch if you are interested in emulating old microprocessors.